# Choice rule and path independence

Tags: relations, economics, social-choice-theory

Let a **choice function** be defined as a function $C:2^X \setminus \{\emptyset\} \rightarrow 2^X$ such that $C(A) \subseteq A$ for all $A \subseteq X$. Here, $2^X$ denotes the power set of $X$. We say a choice function is **path independent** if for all $A, B \in 2^X \setminus \{\emptyset\}$, $C(A \cup B) = C(C(A) \cup C(B))$. We say a choice function is rationalizable if there exists a binary relation $\succeq$ on $X$ that is complete and transitive such that $C(A) = C_{\succeq}(A)$ for all $A \subseteq X$ where $C_{\succeq}(A) = \{x \in A : x \succeq y \text{ for all } y \in A\}$. A choice function is **nonempty** if $C(A) \neq \emptyset$ for all nonempty $A \subseteq X$.

Construct a nonempty choice rule that is path independent but not rationalizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X = \{x,y,z\}$.  For all two-element subsets $A$ of $X$, let $c(A) = A$.  Let $c(X) = \{x,y\}$.  Path independence follows by construction, failure of rationality follows from the existence of a 2-cycle: $x \succ_c z$ $\&$ $z \succsim_c x$.